# Which VM directory is the SSL "Key" stored when using Azure KeyVault?

Tags: ssl, azure-keyvault, jupyterhub

I can see `mycert.cert` and `mycert.prv` but there is no "SSL Key" in the `/var/lib/waagent` directory of the VM I just created.

- Deployed an nginx webserver, with SSL cert, using cloud-init, on ubuntu 17.10 VM using Azure **KeyVault** per the [official instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server#generate-a-certificate-and-store-in-key-vault).
- Installed Jupyter Hub on the VM using the [official instructions here](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation).
- Now I'd like to add the SSL **key** and **cert** to the Jupyter Hub config file [per these instructions](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/config-basics.html?highlight=ssl#configure-using-command-line-options). Its asking for this format:

`jupyterhub --ip x.x.x.x --port 443 --ssl-key my_ssl.key --ssl-cert my_ssl.cert`

Where is this `ssl.key` file?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The `.prv` file is likely the "private" key. It can have a few different extensions. .key, .pem, .prv, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So the .prv file = the .key file? Is there any references for this? With all the worry about "exposing your private keys" you'd think this would be more straightforward.

Comment: @SeaDude, it seems to be referred to as a private key. Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server#create-a-cloud-init-config-to-secure-nginx